# useContext returning undefined when using hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to create a kind of store using react context API and I ran into a problem that when I use the useContext it is returning undefined.
So the code I have is this:

StateProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

//Needed to track the basket and the user info

//DATA LAYER
export const StateContext = createContext();

// BUILD PROVIDER
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    basket: ["asd", "asd"],
};

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
            //add item to basket
            break;
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET':
            //remove item from basket
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

index.js

```
import reducer, { initialState } from './state/reducer';
....

<StateProvider initalState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
</StateProvider>
```

And the problem is on this file, where I try to console log the basket that I get from the reducer.js initalState.

Header.js

```
import { useStateValue } from '../state/StateProvider'
...
function Header() {
    console.log(useContext(StateContext))
    const [{ basket }]= useStateValue();
    console.log(basket);
```

So the error is when I use the `const [{ basket }]= useStateValue();`, it says this : Cannot read property 'basket' of undefined.

Comment: Here is the link for the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/wortz/amazon-clone)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on index.js, initialState was badly written and I was getting no error because of ES6.